# Does anyone know of a proof of the multiplicative central limit theorem?

Tags: returns, lognormal

I have been told there is a multiplicative CLT.  It says that - no matter the shape of returns distributions - if you *multiply* consecutive iid RVs (centered at 1.1, for instance), then a lognormal is the limiting distribution for prices/wealth.  The only criteria I know of is that, for this to work, both the mean and stdev must be finite (no much of a restriction).

First, is my statement of the problem sensible?  Second, if so, where can I find a proof of what is essentially the multiplicative Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: Just take logs and apply CLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X_i$ are positive and iid. Then the multiplicative random variable $$Y_n =X_1 X_2 …….X_n$$  Hence $$log Y_n= logX_1 + logX_2 +….logX_n$$ which is the sum of iid RVs and therefore has a normal distribution in the limit, by the regular CLT.  This means that $Y_n$ has a lognormal distribution in the limit.

Comment: Easier than I thought. I'm surprised this doesn't get explained anywhere I have looked.